# Replace function not replacing text

Tags: python, replace

The code below is for a mad libs game. The first section opens the template (where to-be-changed words are just written as ADJECTIVE or NOUN etc) and has the text saved in a new variable. The second section finds how many of these to-be-changed words there are. The problem is in the third section where im trying to change the template words to user input. While no errors occur, the words arent changed at all when printing at the end.

```
import os, re

# Open a text file depending on input
# Objective completed
working_file = ""
while True:
    filename = input("Name of MADLIB template file with extension: ")
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename)):
       input_file = open(filename, "r")
       working_file = input_file.read()
       input_file.close()
       break
    else:
        print("No such file found")


# Find any instances of ADVERB, VERB, NOUN, ADJECTIVE in working_file
# Objective completed
words_regex = re.compile(r'ADVERB|VERB|NOUN|ADJECTIVE')
words_found = words_regex.findall(working_file)
print(f"The madlibs template countains {words_found}")

# TODO Replace each word type in working_file with user input before writing to text file
for word_type in words_found:
    user_input = input(f"Input an/a {word_type}: ")
    working_file.replace(word_type, user_input, 1)

print(working_file)
```

So a template mad libs text file containing:

> The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby NOUN
> was unaffected by these events.

Is exactly what is printed out in the end.

Comment: You have to assign the result of the replacement back to `working_file`.  Currently, the replacement *is* working, but you're throwing away the result.

Comment: `str.replace` doesn't replace in-place, so you'll have to do `working_file = working_file.replace(word_type, user_input, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

You should assign changes to the changed variable:

```
working_file = working_file.replace(word_type, user_input, 1)
```